# PHP - Include fixed path

Tags: php, menu, path, directory

> ***Updated - Edited***

I want to use a menu PHP file from different directories.

The problem is when i call the file. Example:

```
Include menu.php from categories folder:http://localhost/admin/categories/categories/cars Include
Include menu.php from index folder: http://localhost/admin/categories/cars
Note that the menu file is not in a folder (index /).
```

The problem is add automatically the directory from where i call (inlude) the file before the menu's path. I do not want that, i want the path to be the same for all folder from where i inlude the menu.php

**See the example. On first line, there two categories. "/categories/categories/".**

Comment: Do you mean that you have menu.php in diferent directories?

Comment: Use an absolute path to the file you are including?  `include '/menu.php';`

Comment: bicho No, i want to use the menu.php from different directories.

@RocketHazmat Can you give me an example? I use xammp and i do not think the absolute path is the best way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "use the menu.php from different directories"?  If you want to use the *same* `menu.php` no matter where you are, then absolute paths are the answer.  I guess if you *really* wanted to, then you could use [`set_include_path()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) to change the "include path": `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);`

Comment: @RocketHazmat Made it more cleaner now. Can you give me a "new" answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `include_once` might be more convenient, as this guarantees that it's only included once.

Furthermore, you'd be best off using absolute paths (`include "/menu.php";`). You are currently using a relative path (`include "menu.php";`).

As PHP is a serverside language, you may need to include it from the root-path, meaning that you'd get a path that looks like `/home/username/public_html/menu.php`. The easiest way to go about this would be to include your menu.php like this: `include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/menu.php";`.

To find the exact path where your `menu.php` is located (and thus, find out from what path you need to include it from), run `echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"];` in your menu.php, as it may be a different path than `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute path instead of a relative.

Example: include('/data/web/123456/html/settings/settings.php');

instead of
include('settings.php');

Additionally i think the require_once() function would be more suitable here.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:
1.
@rocket gave you the probable answer to your questions but you ignored it:
If you include the file like '/menu.php' mind the '/' it will include a menu.php file that relies on the root folder. Adapt it to your needs, but don't forget the slash.

2.
How about using `dirname(__DIR__)` as path folowed by the name of your file. In your case:

```
include  dirname(__DIR__).'/menu.php'
```

Comment: The problem is add automatically the directory from where i call (inlude) the file before the menu's path. I do not want that, i want the path to be the same for all folder from where i inlude the menu.php